# Execution time difference between https and http after taking response

Tags: node.js, https, httprequest

I have a web server that answers to GET requests via Http or Https.
I am accessing the same path on the server from two different simple Nodejs applications: one does Http request and the other does Https request.

When I look at the execution time after response, the Http execution time is 5 times larger than Https execution time. Something is weird, I couldn't figure out. The numbers are not one time, I have executed them multiple times and those numbers are always in the same range.

The server side is implemented with Ruby on Rails behind Nginx server.

What is the difference between them makes this difference?

Https request Nodejs Code:

```
options  = {
              hostname            : "localhost",
              port                : "1443",
              cookieJar           : true,
              rejectUnauthorized  : false,
              method              : "GET",
              headers             : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
              path                : '/issuer/create_tls'
};


req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  var start = process.hrtime();
  var obj;
  res.on('data', (chunk)=>{
      obj = JSON.parse(chunk);
  }).on('end',()=>{
      var elapsed = process.hrtime(start)[1] / 1000000;
      console.log("elapsed time:", elapsed);
  });
});

req.end();
```

```
Https elapsed time: 1.187865
```

Http request Nodejs code:

```
options = {host: "localhost", port: '3010', method: 'GET', path: '/issuer/create_tls'};

req = http.request(options, (res)=>{
    var start1 = process.hrtime();
    var obj;
    res.on('data', (chunk)=>{
        obj = JSON.parse(chunk);
    }).on('end',()=>{
        var elapsed1 = process.hrtime(start1)[1] / 1000000;
        console.log("Http elapsed time:", elapsed1);
    });

});

req.end();
```

```
Http elapsed time: 5.11164
```

Comment: Maybe you should also add the listener application.

Comment: The matter is about after response, why do you want to see the listener?

Comment: Maybe it's functionality differs from HTTP to HTTPS. Maybe your HTTPS server implements SPDY or H/2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the server side is implemented with Ruby on Rails behind Nginx server.

Comment: The thing is, this one is not a good test I know, but I am trying to understand which one performs better in nodejs side. I naively thought that I could just distinguish the networking time from the cpu time, when I start measuring it from the response started.